# Datefield error value from db

Tags: extjs, datefield

i try populate a datefield from db value. The db value is: '1940-09-17', the datefield is:

```
{ fieldLabel:  'Fecha de nacimiento', name: 'fechaNacimiento', xtype: 'datefield', 
 allowBlank: false, format: 'Y-m-d'}
```

But when show the datefield, the value is '2040-09-17'. the GET info is:

> {"success":true,"total":1,"data":{"idUsuario":34,"nombre":"Pepe","apellido":"Argento","dni":120934873,"domicilio":"122
>   n\u00b0 1191","fechaNacimiento":"09/17/40","email":""}}

Why show a bad value ?. Any idea ?.

Comment: We're closer to `2040` than `1940`.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should always send a 4 digits year (2040 or 1940, not 40) to prevent this kind of situations.

Comment: How ? i get the date from a db query. The value in the db is "1940-09-17" ... Why return a 2 digit year ?